# Fixed marker size at the android Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any possibility to make marker static?
I don't need to increese/reduce marker size while zoom is changing.
I know about groundoverlay - it's not an option here.

The result should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Why? the marker will disappear if you zoom-out once more.

Comment: Yes, sure. But currently i have to set scale of marker like on the picture. It wouldn't be dynamic. It must be as a ground overlay

Comment: @inaps: were you able to solve this ? I have the same issue

Comment: The official documentation says "markers do not change size based on zoom. Use GroundOverlays if you desire this effect". Why is a ground overlay not acceptable?

Comment: Why `GroundOverlay` "it's not an option here." ?

Answer (score 4):

[Ben P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8298909/ben-p) is right in his comment: "markers do not change size based on zoom". But this marker behavior can be achieved by deleting and re-creating the marker with custom icon size in (for example) [`onCameraIdle()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.html#onCameraIdle()) for each zoom level. With:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int DIAMETER_IN_METERS = 300;

    private final LatLng MARKER_LOCATION = new LatLng(37.762555, -122.244221);

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;

    private Marker mMarker = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {

                if (mMarker != null) {
                    mMarker.remove();
                }
                mMarker = createResizedMarker(MARKER_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MARKER_LOCATION, 16));
    }

    private Marker createResizedMarker(LatLng marker_location) {
        // get vector drawable
        final Drawable iconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_letter_m);
        // calc map resolution (meters per pixel) for current zoom level for details see e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940990.aspx
        final double meters_per_pixel = (Math.cos(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.pow(2, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));
        // calc marker icon diameter in pixels
        final int diameter = (int)(DIAMETER_IN_METERS / meters_per_pixel);
        // create marker icon bitmap for current scale
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(diameter, diameter, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        iconDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        iconDrawable.draw(canvas);

        Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(MARKER_LOCATION)
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));

        return marker;
    }
}
```

and `R.drawable.ic_letter_m` - `xml` vector drawable (for perfect scaling) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="512dp"
        android:height="512dp"
        android:viewportWidth="512"
        android:viewportHeight="512">

    <path
        android:name="canvas_background"
        android:pathData="M -1 -1 H 581 V 401 H -1 V -1 Z" />
    <path
        android:name="SVGCleanerId_0"
        android:fillColor="#54BBFF"
        android:pathData="M256,0l-61.811005,256l61.811005,256c141.384979,0 256,-114.61499
256,-256s-114.61499,-256 -256,-256z" />
    <path
        android:name="SVGCleanerId_1"
        android:fillColor="#8DD2FF"
        android:pathData="M0,256c0,141.384979 114.614998,256 256,256l0,-512c-141.385002,0 -256,114.614998
-256,256z" />
    <path
        android:name="svg_1"
        android:fillColor="#C6E8FF"
        android:pathData="M256,30.905001l0,450.188993c124.31601,0 225.095001,-100.777985
225.095001,-225.095001s-100.778992,-225.093992 -225.095001,-225.093992z" />
    <path
        android:name="svg_2"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M450.188995,256c0,-124.315994 -86.94101,-225.094999
-194.188995,-225.094999c-124.315994,0 -225.094999,100.779005
-225.094999,225.094999s100.779005,225.095001 225.094999,225.095001c107.247986,0
194.188995,-100.778992 194.188995,-225.095001z" />
    <path
        android:name="svg_3"
        android:fillColor="#54BBFF"
        android:pathData="M306.993988,395.589996c-11.378998,0 -20.604004,-9.223999
-20.604004,-20.604004l0,-137.592987l-11.453003,26.722992c-3.246002,7.576019
-10.694977,12.488007 -18.937988,12.488007c-8.240997,0 -15.69101,-4.912018
-18.938004,-12.488007l-11.453003,-26.722992l0,137.593018c0,11.378998
-9.223999,20.603973 -20.604004,20.603973c-11.378998,0 -20.603989,-9.223999
-20.603989,-20.603973l0,-237.972015c0,-9.782997 6.878998,-18.215996
16.460999,-20.182999c9.584,-1.968002 19.227005,3.075005
23.080002,12.065994l32.059006,74.798004l32.056,-74.796997c3.852997,-8.990997
13.502014,-14.032997 23.079987,-12.066002c9.583008,1.968002 16.460999,10.401001
16.460999,20.183006l0,237.971985c0.001007,11.377991 -9.223999,20.602997
-20.602997,20.602997z" />
    <path
        android:name="SVGCleanerId_0_1_"
        android:fillColor="#F655A0"
        android:pathData="M256,0l-61.811005,256l61.811005,256c141.384979,0 256,-114.61499
256,-256s-114.61499,-256 -256,-256z" />
    <path
        android:name="SVGCleanerId_1_1_"
        android:fillColor="#F655A0"
        android:pathData="M0,256c0,141.384979 114.614998,256 256,256l0,-512c-141.385002,0 -256,114.614998
-256,256z" />
    <path
        android:name="svg_8"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M335.771271,393.589996c-17.577087,0 -31.826935,-9.223999
-31.826935,-20.604004l0,-137.592987l-17.691406,26.722992c-5.014069,7.576019
-16.520477,12.488007 -29.253418,12.488007c-12.729828,0 -24.237839,-4.912018
-29.253448,-12.488007l-17.691406,-26.722992l0,137.593018c0,11.378998
-14.248276,20.603973 -31.82692,20.603973c-17.577087,0 -31.826889,-9.223999
-31.826889,-20.603973l0,-237.972015c0,-9.782997 10.625946,-18.215996
25.427231,-20.182999c14.804367,-1.968002 29.699875,3.075005
35.651581,12.065994l49.521408,74.798004l49.516754,-74.796997c5.951721,-8.990997
20.856506,-14.032997 35.651581,-12.066002c14.802826,1.968002 25.427216,10.401001
25.427216,20.183006l0,237.971985c0.001556,11.377991 -14.24826,20.602997
-31.825348,20.602997z" />
</vector>
```

you got something like:

[image: Marker resize]

But indeed, [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay) do all that job from the box. It's really better to use Ground Overlays for task like that (at least for better performance and smooth zooming). And if you need, e.g. in case you need to draw car movement, you can recreate Ground Overlays (with different bitmaps or bitmaps size like markers above) in any time. You can also rotate Ground Overlays like markers with [`.setBearing()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html#setBearing(float)).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using the following code for the solution. You may use the following code for a fixed-size marker. As of my study for this, we have only Bitmap option.

```
int height = 100;
int width = 100;
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.marker);
Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

To add market use the following code:

```
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(POSITION)
                        .title("Title")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))
                );
```

Comment: if you found any of the above solutions is helpful please accept the most relevant answer, such that it could help other developers.